# Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE

Tags: maven, maven-3, spring-batch

### Im getting following error in eclipse, while working in spring batch..for all projects..

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE 
 from http://central.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval 
 of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-
 parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE from/to central (http://central.maven.org/maven2/): proxy.somewhere.com and 'parent.relativePath'

### points at wrong local POM

I tried all the answers here...nothing worked so far..
Its working at home network...bt not in office..
I also changed the settings.xml file with proxy, bt no use..
Following is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-batch-processing</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
</repository>
```

```
 settings.xml:

  ------------------------------------------
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <localRepository/>
   <interactiveMode/>
   <usePluginRegistry/>
   <offline/>
   <pluginGroups/>
    <servers/>
    <mirrors/>
   <proxies>
    <proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
    <port>7321</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
   </proxies>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
```

Thanks,
Anandan R

Comment: What is the _proxy.somewhere.com_ thing?

Comment: Well I guess you just have to remove that proxy definition, unless you _really_ have access to a proxy located @ _proxy.somewhere.com:7321_

Comment: @Tome : then how my setting.xml should be?

Comment: If you don't need any proxy to access the outside world, just remove that _settings.xml_ file. As usual with Maven, you only have to declare things when the defaults do not suit you.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438742/332465

Answer (score 2):

Above error is coming because http://central.maven.org/maven2/ is failing to get org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE dependency.

I was also getting the same with

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

which was resolved after below changes:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

Kindly check once and give your feedback whether its gone or not for you...