# Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am creating simple spring boot web application
I am using the project generated by spring Initializer

I have set my JDK and maven in the path
Also done setting for JAVA_HOME

While running the application getting following error

Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (repo.maven.apache.org) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]

following is my POM in the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.iot.tme</groupId>
<artifactId>PowerBIDemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>PowerBIDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: did u find a solution to it ?

Comment: Migrate to Gradle and it will works perfectly...

Answer (score 8):

try to update maven dependencies by hands `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`.

Comment: Worked for me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Incase you're working for an organisation and need VPN to work. You must connect to VPN before downloading the dependencies. This is what resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I changed jdk 1.7 to jdk 1.8 and It worked and Don't forget also update your environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using wrong JDK version (1.7) and changing it to (1.8) worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was that I downloaded the cacerts file provided in the same repository and stored that in the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder and then I right clicked the Project in the Package Explorer view of Eclipse, Project -> Maven -> Update Project (Alt+F5), and after that it started downloading the dependencies, from the various repos which were unreachable earlier, and later the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i have already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61450410/2606228).
try deleting the dependencies in .m2 and update and clean.

and also check the settings.xml is properly configured in window-->preferences-->maven-->User Settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me it work by changing option settings of Netbeans.
`Tools > Options > Team > Maven > Maven Home`

Update by downloading maven manually from original website
check maven by using `mvn -v`. extra inst.(http://maven.apache.org/install.html)

Once Maven is installed, add the maven directory to Maven Home:

`Tools > Options > Team > Maven > Maven Home`

Comment: Isn't your answer missing something? It seems you wanted to type something after :

Comment: Yup. thanx.@Ruli

Answer (score 0):

Delete .m2 folder which is located in your C drive and try updating the maven project. it will again create a folder .m2 and will add the repositories to it. This worked for me. Try once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificates for the domains you want to download files from to your Java Cacerts File.

If you are behind a firewall and/or using a VPN or in a corporate environment you will need to add extra certificates

Go to https://repo.spring.io in the Chrome browser and then export the certificates by right clicking on the lock icon in the URL address bar, and then 'Connection is Secure,' then 'Connection is Valid' and the 'Details'. From there you can export one or more certificates.

Add these certificates to your Java Runtime cacerts using Java's keytool utility like this ( exact command will vary )

`keytool -trustcacerts -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias certificate-alias -import exported-CRT-file`

Answer (score -1):

delete .m2 directory and run mvn clean. Worked for me

For mac users, to get .m2 folder

Open your terminal and Type open ~/.m2

Comment: Be careful, because `.m2` folder contains other stuff rather than the local repository. E.g. the user wide `settings.xml` is placed under `.m2` folder.